# How to get dirt on skyblock?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am playing skyblock and need more dirt. I know I can make coarse dirt and till it to dirt but I need gravel for that. How can I get gravel on a skyblock if I only have a tree, an infinite water source, a cobblestone generator and some dirt?
I am playing on Minecraft Pocket Edition.

Answer (score 8):

Now that the 1.16 update is out you can give a Piglin gold ingots and there's a 9% chance to receive gravel blocks, from which you can get [dirt](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Coarse_Dirt).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no more dirt for you.

The normal Skyblock does not give you any extra dirt other than what's already available on your island.

Answer (score 2):

In some skyblock games you can go to a shop and Buy dirt from the shop. Sometimes chests spawn next to you too which can contain dirt. Such as Cubecraft, Lifeboat etc...

Answer (score -1):

> This is in a CubeCraft perspective.

Yes, there is limited dirt for you, but your dreams are not crushed yet.

If you have enough coins (at least 100), then you can buy more dirt with the amount you need.

Comment: What are you quoting, and why did you make your answer Community Wiki?

Comment: @Wrigglenite This question really doesn't need to be recognized. As a CubeCraft player (which I can't [get in now](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/382418/i-cant-enter-cubecraft-servers)), I like this question and I answered it anyway. But since it is an old question, it wouldn't really add anything much (at least I think it doesn't). It won't gain much recognition, so it's a community-wiki worth choosing for me.